# In Lost Series 2 Episode 24, why does everybody act as if the massive explosion didn't happen?

Tags: lost

In Lost Series 2 Episode 24, [Live Together, Die Alone](https://lostpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Live_Together,_Die_Alone), everybody acts as if the massive explosion didn't happen.

They close their eyes and ears but that's all. Nobody asks any questions. Nobody talks about what just happened.

What's the explanation for this?

Comment: To be fair, this is hardly the weirdest unexplained thing that happens in *Lost*.

Comment: The simplest answer is that the show was intentionally weird, with odd, unexplained occurrences that were intended to provoke speculation without necessarily making sense or ever being resolved - "*The entire island is a magic box"*

Comment: In universe, it wasn’t an explosion, was it? The station imploded from a build up of magnetic energy, and the sound we hear isn’t “explosion-y”, so there’s probably nothing localisable about it. (So you’d just sort of shrug and say “the island is being weird again”, and go back to dealing with the more important immediate issues like the ongoing standoff.)

Comment: @user3722246  In US tv, all the episodes of a program constitute a series.  A batch of episodes ordered by the network and produced as a set are called a season,.  Therefore you are asking about Lost,, season 2, episode 24 "Live Together, Die Alone".

Comment: My theory is that the Others were in the presence of Hurley, whom they were going to let go, and they didn't want him knowing what they know. The Others seem very militarily regimented, which would included aggressive protection of information, both from the enemy and from themselves. So called "need to know". Just a few episodes earlier, Ben (as we learn later is is real name) went through extravagant stories and severe beatings and mistreatment to protect his identity and information he might know.